# linq after the join groupby and select

Tags: linq, join, group-by

I need to construct a linq like this in regular sql query command:

```
select t1.vendorcode, t1.location, sum(t1.sales)
from table1 t1
where t1(vendorCode, location) in
      (select t2.vendorCode, t2.location from table2 t2) 
groupby t1.vendorCode, t1.location
```

I construct the linq as following:

```
query = from t1 in table1
where ...
join t2 in table2 on new
{
  t2.vendorcode, t2.location
} equals new
{ 
  t1.vendorcode, t1.location 
}
```

The question I have is: How should I construct this linq? Do I need another subquery or  can i add more `group by` and select statement to complete this linq?

Comment: Regular sql query? In which rdbms does that work?

Comment: The regular sql query may not constructed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add another `group by` clause - you just need to select the sum:

```
var query = from t1 in table1
            join t2 in table2 
              on new { t1.vendorcode, t1.location } equals
                 new { t2.vendorcode, t2.location }
            group t1 by new { t1.vendorcode, t1.location } into g
            select new { 
                g.Key.vendorcode,
                g.Key.location, 
                g.Sum(t1 => t1.sale)
            };
```

That will work *if* there's only a single record in `table2` with any particular vendorcode/location pair. However, if there can be *multiple* records like that, then it doesn't work - and you probably want something more like:

```
var query = from t1 in table1
            where table2.Select(t2 => new { t2.vendorcode, t2.location })
                        .Contains(new { t1.vendorcode, t1.location })
            group t1 by new { t1.vendorcode, t1.location } into g
            select new { 
                g.Key.vendorcode,
                g.Key.location, 
                g.Sum(t1 => t1.sale)
            };
```

That's logically your "exists" version.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for your help!!! I still have problem with this query, I am using your approach 2 because t2 has more than one rows and t2 is a List<Object> - List<VendorLocationObject>. The syntax looks ok and compiled, but when I run it, it return an exception "Unable to process the type 'Anonymous type, because it has no known mapping to the value layer'. VendorLocation is a structure of         public struct VendorLocation
        {
            public string VendorCode;
            public string Location;
        }

Comment: @user2008910: Why are you using a struct for that? I don't know whether it's relevant to the problem, but it's certainly odd. You should work out which bit of the query is causing problems... is it the `where` clause, the grouping, the summing...?

Comment: Hi Jon, I have already eliminated all the parts and the structure is definitely the problem. The reason I am using the structure is because it contains all the filter values which users selected from a tree list UI. I have a List<VendorLocation>  struct VendorLocation is {string vendorCode, string Location}. Any suggestions?

Comment: The List may contain more than one object. It looks like I can not join the list with the actual sql table.

Comment: @user2008910: You haven't explained *why it's a struct*. Why not use a class, which would be more conventional?

Comment: Jon, thank you for your help! I can use a class if it will work.

Comment: I just convert the struct into a class and it is still doesn't work, the same error message "Unable to process the type 'Anonymous type, because it has no known mapping to the value layer".

Comment: @user2008910: Okay, you definitely need to do some more digging. Currently you've got filtering, grouping and joining. What happens if you *just* group entries in table 1? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, I did that already it was working fine. So I know the error messages is coming from the struct or class. It looks like we can not mix linq to sql with linq to object.

Comment: I think thinking maybe I should add the class or struct into the entity framework? Should I add a complex type or an entity?

Comment: @user2008910: I don't know what you mean by "add [it] into the entity framework" - but yes, EF would need to know about it. If that's not enough, I suggest you add *much more information* to your question, and hope that someone with more EF knowledge answers; it's not really a good idea to just keep going in comments like this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var query =
    from t1 in table1

    join t2 in table2
    on new { vc = t1.vendorcode, lc = t1.location }
    equals new { vc = t2.vendorcode, lc = t2.location }

    group t1 by new { vc = t1.vendorcode, lc = t1.location };
```

Comment: That doesn't perform the summing part.